# How to perform a right outer join in Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I needed to perform a right outer join in Mongo db. I know we can use $lookup to perform left outer join. I needed to know is there any way to perform right outer join in Mongo db?

Answer (score 4):

`Table A Left Outer Join Table B`and `Table B Right Outer Join Table A` are equivalent in the SQL world only difference you will have is the order of the columns.

Similarly Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in mongodb which performs a left outer join. Since your requirement is to perform Right Outer Join, reverse the order of the collections.